# Atlassian BitBucket server addon web-item section name

Tags: bitbucket, add-on, bitbucket-server

After trying a number of different sections, I figured I'd ask - would anyone know the name of the WORKFLOW section depicted on the screenshot below? The snippet below should give an idea of what I am trying to do.

```
<web-item key="my-project-item" name="My Title" section="stash.repository.settings.panel/repository-settings-section" weight="300" application="stash"> .... </web-item>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the information you are looking for:

```
Web Item: bitbucket.repository.settings.panel/repository-workflow-section
Web Panel: example-web-item.badge
Context Items: request, principal, repository, project
```

You can get this by appending `?web.items&web.panels&web.sections` to the URL in Bitbucket Server.

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer I was looking for. If you have a link to good documentation resource, I would appreciate it as well.

Comment: You're welcome! This wiki page might help you: https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/server/docs/latest/reference/web-fragments.html